# Does SFINAE apply to function bodies?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, overload-resolution, upcasting

I have the following sample code:

```
class Serializable {};

class MyData : public Serializable {};

void GetData( Serializable& ) {}

template<typename T>
void GetData( T& data )
{
    std::istringstream s{"test"};
    s >> data;
}

int main()
{
    MyData d;
    GetData(d);
}
```

([Live Sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/714cccdfa131169e))

Based on overload resolution rules, the non-template version should be preferred because the base class is of type `Serializable`. However, I expect SFINAE to kick in when there are errors in the template version when it is instantiated for overload resolution (because if the >> operator is not defined for a type, it should not be considered).

Why is it still failing even though the template won't be used?

Comment: `the non-template version should be preferred` only if it's an exact match. See what happens if you do `MyData` instead of `Serializable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Based on overload resolution rules, the non-template version should be
>   preferred because the base class is of type `Serializable`.

Not quite. [over.match.best]:

> Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a
>   better function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments
>   i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then
>
> - for some argument j, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICSj(F2), **or, if not that,**
> - […]
> - `F1` is not a function template specialization and `F2` is a function template specialization […]

That means that only if the deduced specialization of the function template necessitates a conversion that isn't better than the conversion that the normal function necessitates, your rule applies.
And the binding of `d` to `Serializable&` is a worse conversion than the binding of d to `MyData&` (which is the type of the parameter of the specialization), [over.ics.ref]:

> When a parameter of reference type binds directly (8.5.3) to an
>   argument expression, **the implicit conversion sequence is the identity
>   conversion, unless the argument expression has a type that is a
>   derived class of the parameter type, in which case the implicit
>   conversion sequence is a derived-to-base Conversion (13.3.3.1).**

> However, I expect SFINAE to kick in when there are errors in the
>   template version when it is instantiated for overload resolution
>   (because if the >> operator is not defined for a type, it should not
>   be considered).

SFINAE doesn't apply for the content of a function template. [temp.deduct]/8:

> Only invalid types and expressions **in the immediate context of the
>   function type and its template parameter types** can result in a
>   deduction failure.

Hence the deduced specialization of the function template is indeed chosen, and causes a compiler error while instantiating its definition.

Comment: The standards usage of the word "specialization" here is really "instantiation" of the template then, correct? Because specialization in my mind is when a function is explicitly implemented for types. In my case I am not explicitly specializing the base function template.

Comment: @void.pointer It seems you've mixed up the terminology. The *specialization* is the function that was instantiated with the deduced template arguments. What you're talking about is an *explicit specialization*.